# Regex - Invalid Quantifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this regex in JavaScript which is to evaluate if a given string matches some german phone number patterns.

```
var reg = new RegExp("(?:\+\d+)?\s*(?:\(\d+\)\s*(?:[/–-]\s*)?)?\d+(?:\s*(?:[\s/–-]\s*)?\d+)*");
```

When using it I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid quantifier

...eg = new RegExp("(?:\+\d+)\s*(?:\(\d+\)\s*(?:[/–-]\s*))\d+(?:\s*(?:[\s/–-]\s*)\d...
```

I'm trying hard to learn reading regular expressions, but can not understand them full yet. I did not write this expression by myself and I am struggling to understand it.

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using a string litteral, you need to escape each backslash:

```
(?:\\+\\d+)?\\s*(?:\\(\\d+\\)\\s*(?:[/–-]\\s*)?)?\\d+(?:\\s*(?:[\\s/–-]\\s*)?\\d+)*
```

The other solution would be to use the regex litteral:

```
var reg = /(?:\+\d+)?\s*(?:\(\d+\)\s*(?:[\/–-]\s*)?)?\d+(?:\s*(?:[\s\/–-]\s*)?\d+)*/;
```

Answer (score 2):

`new RegExp` requires a string, and since backslashes already have meaning inside strings, they need to be escaped again.

In your case, though, you're using a static pattern, so you'd be better off with a literal:

```
var reg = /(?:\+\d+)?\s*(?:\(\d+\)\s*(?:[\/–-]\s*)?)?\d+(?:\s*(?:[\s\/–-]\s*)?\d+)*/;
```

Just be aware that you need to escape `/` here ;)

As an additional tip, you can simplify the need to escape things to some extent by doing stuff like `[+]` for a literal `+`. I think it looks nicer then `\+`, but that's just my opinion.